# How to check the exist value

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net and Sql Server

I want to check the user Entry Value.

The User is entering the code in the textbox, before saving to the table, i want to check whethere code is already exist in the table or not.

Tried Code

```
 cmd = New SqlCommand("Select code from table where code = '" & textbox1.Text & "' ", Con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read()

       End While
```

If value is exist, then message to the user "Already Exist" other wise save to the table.

Need Vb.net Code Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SELECT COUNT instead and then check for that being greater than zero:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from table where code = '" & textbox1.Text & "' ", con)
Dim NumRecords as Int32 = cmd.ExecuteScalar
IF NumRecords > 0 THEN...
```

Comment: With a large table count could be slow.  You could get around this by using `SELECT top 1 * from table where code = '" & textbox1.Text & "' "` and then check if the record count is greater than 0 (or == 1).

Answer (score 0):

Make code as primary key since you want it to be unique

if the value entered by the user in code is already existing in the table , VIOLATION of primary key sql exception will be thrown

Catch that exception and display a warning message!